# Tags with "+" in them broke recently

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-search

It seems that the parsing of tags with plusses (`+`) in them broke recently. This is very inconvenient for topics like C++.

See these questions tagged with `c++`: ["[c++]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
Now, if you select another tag from the list on the right, such as "templates", it *used* to bring you to ["[c++] [templates]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20templates). However, as of fairly recently (somewhere in the last month or so), it started bringing you to ["[c+++templates]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+templates). It appears that the space in the URL (encoded as `%20`) has been replaced by a `+`.

This is especially weird for tags that have a `+` in the middle, like `c++11`. If you go to ["[c++11]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), and again select "templates" on the right, it breaks down into ["[c] [11] [templates]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11+templates).

It seems that the thing that generates the search URLs is missing a URL encoding step.

Comment: What's your Web browser?

Comment: I repro-ed this on Chrome

Comment: Going by archive.org, looks like this has been broken since at least the 26th. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Related bug on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362508/bug-when-combining-boolean-search-operators-with-tags-containing-plus-signs

Comment: This will be my fault; I've been overhauling that code as part of a new feature - I obviously missed a key scenario. It will be rectified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should now be fixed; sorry about that.

Edit: well, I fixed half of it: the tags on the right should work fine, but now switching tab is unreliable with tags like C++ - working on that too!

(and: done)

Comment: But what went wrong?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it turns out the code was meant to be "right"; instead it was "not right" :) more specifically, there's some subtle things that happen on how `+` is treated depending on whether a URL is %-encoded or not; i.e. without other characters being %-encoded, + can be used for space - but with the %-encoding it needs to be %20 instead

Comment: Ouch, sounds complicated and delicate... kudos for fixing!

Comment: Seems semi related - but I've just wanted to merge a couple of tags with a `+` in them on SO and had to hand wrangle the URLs for those to work. Picking another two for an example (not actually doing anything with them! (C++ and C++14)) I get a url of: `mastertag=c%252b%252b%2b&removetag=c%252b%252b14` and told that: *c2b2b14 will be removed from 0 questions* and *c2b2b+ will be added to 0 questions*.... it's hardly a common operation and can be gotten around easily enough - just a wee bit inconvenient...

Comment: @JonClements yup, something broke; looking

Comment: @JonClements fixed next build

Comment: Glad it was a quick fix. Thanks mate.